# Why is QuickTime’s volume significantly softer than VLC’s?

Tags: video, audio, vlc-media-player, quicktime

I have a Unibody Macbook running 10.5.5. When I play videos in QuickTime the audio is low even after I raise both the QuickTime volume meter and the system volume meter to the maximum. When I play the same videos in VLC, the VLC volume meter allows me to raise it to a louder level.

Why is this?

Is there a tool for the Mac that allows me to amplify my sound outside of VLC?

Answer (score 2):

VLC's sound level goes up to 400%. Quicktime maxes out at 100%. I'm not sure why that is, but that's one of the reasons I use VLC instead of Quicktime.

Comment: it's because VLC beyond 100% artificially amplifies the wavform.  no problem if the wavform is quiet, but if loud you'll get distortion.

Comment: Is there an app that can artificially amplify sound for the general system volume?

Comment: i have one called "external volume knob on my powered speakers"...

Comment: Note that you could probably damage your macbook speakers by putting the volume above %100 using VLC, depending on the source. VLC lets you do it in case the original waveform is super quiet, but unless there is a hardware or software to limit the speaker volume, beware.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to boost the volume by holding down shift while adjusting the volume.  [See this lifeclever tip](http://www.lifeclever.com/pump-up-the-volume-in-quicktime/), which seems to be regarding a rather old version of QT.  Not sure if this still applies to QuickTime X -- can anyone verify that?

Comment: That's a neat trick.  I'm running 10.5 so I don't know if it works on QuickTime X.  The QuickTime on 10.5 doesn't have the volume meter shown in the screenshot, so you can't do the shift trick.  QTAmateur (http://www.mikeash.com/?page=software/qtamateur/index.html) does though and it works there great.